# How can I force a process to return from a call to select() while debugging it

Tags: linux, gdb, valgrind

I'm running a server under gdb, and it's currently blocked in a call to select.

I want to make it return from select, after which I can manually modify the fd sets and see how execution continues.

I tried to put a breakpoint on the next line after the call to select(), and issued the command 'signal SIGINT', but that did nothing other than printing 'Continuing with signal SIGINT'.

edit: I'm actually debugging using vgdb, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure of you can do this, but since you only want this for debugging purpose you can just add a file descriptor to your fd set (creating a named pipe e.g). Thus, during the debugging, the select normally will be blocked waiting for input on any of its file-descriptors, but you can unlock the call by just writing something to your named pipe (through a the terminal). I'm not sure if this fulfill your needs but it may work as simple workaround for the debugging sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `jump` command.  This takes a location similar to how `break` takes a location, so you can specify a line, or an address as `*ADDR`.  Try `help jump` at the gdb prompt for more information.

I've generally had most success with this command when the distance that I jump is small, otherwise, too much program state is incorrect for the program to do anything sane, but jumping out of a system call, especially if the plan is to patch up the return state anyway might work well.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind gdbserver+vgdb only partially supports the GDB command 'signal sig'
since version 3.11 (which was just released the 23 September 2015.
Version 3.10 and before are completely ignoring the GDB instruction
to continue with a signal or to change the signal.

In release 3.11, 'signal SIG' is partially supported: if the process
reported a signal to GDB, the signal can be ignored (using signal 0)
or can be changed (using signal othersignr).

Valgrind gdbserver does currently not support to raise a signal from GDB.

Also, when a thread is blocked in a system call, the Valgrind gdbserver
will not accept the GDB instruction to 'jump' out or 'return' from the
syscall.